# How to create generic 2d array in python

Tags: python, numpy, generics

In Java you would do it like this: `Node[][] nodes;` where Node.java is a custom class. How do I do it in python where Node.py:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self.memory = []
    self.temporal_groups = []
```

I have imported `numpy` and created an object type

```
typeObject = numpy.dtype('O') # O stands for python objects
nodes = ???
```

Comment: You are going to create identical objects? `nodes = [[Node() for j in range(4)] for i in range(5)]` will give you an [5][4] array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way, inside your node class create a function that will return the generic array:

```
def genArray(a, b):
    return [[0 for y in range(a)] for x in range(b)]
```

then you can assign them the way you want. Maybe you might change the 0 to your node object. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have two easy options: use `numpy` or declare a nested list. The latter approach is more conceptually similar to `Node[][]` since it allows for ragged lists, as does Java, but the former approach will probably make processing faster.

**numpy arrays**

To make an array in `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.full((m, n), None, dtype=np.object)
```

In `numpy`, you have to have some idea about the size of the array (here `m`, `n`) up-front. There are ways to grow an array, but they are not very efficient, especially for large arrays. [`np.full`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) will initialize your array with a copy of whatever reference you want. You can modify the elements as you wish after that.

**Python lists**

To create a ragged list, you do not have to do much:

```
x = []
```

This creates an empty list. This is equivalent to `Node[][]` in Java because that declares a list too. The main difference is that Python lists can change size and are untyped. They are effectively always `Object[]`.

To add more dimensions to the list, just do `x[i] = 
[]`, which will insert a nested list into your outer list. This is similar to defining something like

```
Node[][] nodes = new Node[m][];
nodes[i] = new Node[n];
```

where `m` is the number of nested lists (rows) and `n` is the number of elements in each list (columns). Again, the main difference is that once you have a list in Python, you can expand or contract it as you Java.

Manipulate with `x[i][j]` as you would in Java. You can add new sublists by doing `x.append([])` or `x[i] = []`, where `i` is an index past the end of `x`.